# Searching for string in comma separated list

Tags: python

The list is present in User.log file.

I have extracted the list line by line using python from User.log file.

```
SHRAMIK,STUDENT,CSE,34, 
KESHAV,TEACHER,MECH,12
```

```
list = ['SHRAMIK,STUDENT,CSE,34', 'KESHAV,TEACHER,MECH,12']
search_value = "SHRAMIK"
```

My CODE:

```
with open('User.Log') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    print(type(lines))
    data = lines[0].split(",")
    print("NEW LINES =============== >" ,lines)
    print("NEW DATA =============== >" , data , "Roll No FROM LIST IS :", data[3])
```

MY OUTPUT:

```
('NEW LINES =============== >', ['SHRAMIK,STUDENT,CSE,34', 'KESHAV,TEACHER,MECH,12'])
('NEW DATA =============== >', ['SHRAMIK,STUDENT,CSE,34'], 'Roll No FROM LIST IS :', '34'
```

So I am not getting anything to the point to search for the NAME and retrieve the ROLL NO with respect to the NAME using Python. Please do you have any idea how should I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there - you split the line to its components, now you just need to compare the name to the search value:

```py
with open('User.Log') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split(',')
        if line[0] == search_value:
             print('Rollno is ' + line[3])
             break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
with open('User.Log') as f:
    for data in f:
        if data.split(',')[0] == searchKey:
            print("Found student with Roll number {}".format(data.split(',')[3])
            break
    else:
        print("not found with name {}".format(searchKey))  #else is outside the for loop
```

---

> The *else* block just after *for/while* is executed only when the loop is **NOT** terminated by a ***break*** statement.